# Python N-body simulation code giving incorrect answer

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I have written some python code to solve the N-body problem using the Euler method. The code runs without problems and seems to give a reasonable answer (e.g. if there are two particles then the start moving towards each other). However when I run this simulation over a large number of iterations I see that the particles (say I run it with two particles) pass by each other (I do not consider collisions) and keep going in their directions indefinitely. This violates the conservation of energy and so there must be a flaw in my code but I am unable to find it. Could anyone please find it and explain my mistake.

Thank you.

Thanks to @samgak for pointing out that I was updating the particles twice. I have now fixed this but the problem still keeps coming. I have also replicated  the output I get when I run this simulation with two stationary particles at (0,0) and (1,0) with a time step of 1 second and 100000 iterations:

Particle with mass: 1 and position: [234.8268420043934, 0.0] and velocity: [0.011249111128594091, 0.0]

Particle with mass: 1 and position: [-233.82684200439311, 0.0] and velocity: [-0.011249111128594091, 0.0]

Also thanks to @PM2Ring for pointing out some optimizations I could make and the perils of using the Euler method.

Code:

```
import math
class Particle:
    """
    Class to represent a single particle
    """
    def __init__(self,mass,position,velocity):
        """
        Initialize the particle
        """
        self.G = 6.67408*10**-11 #fixed throughout the simulation
        self.time_interval = 10**0 #fixed throughout the simulation, gives the interval between updates
        self.mass = mass
        self.position = position #should be a list
        self.velocity = velocity #should be a list
        self.updated_position = position
        self.updated_velocity = velocity
    def __str__(self):
        """
        String representation of particle
        """
        return "Particle with mass: " + str(self.mass) + " and position: " + str(self.position) + " and velocity: " + str(self.velocity)
    def get_mass(self):
        """
        Returns the mass of the particle
        """
        return self.mass
    def get_position(self):
        """
        returns the position of the particle
        """
        return self.position
    def get_velocity(self):
        """
        returns the velocity of the particle
        """
        return self.velocity
    def get_updated_position(self):
        """
        calculates the future position of the particle
        """
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            self.updated_position[i] = self.updated_position[i] + self.time_interval*self.velocity[i]
    def update_position(self):
        """
        updates the position of the particle
        """
        self.position = self.updated_position.copy()
    def get_distance(self,other_particle):
        """
        returns the distance between the particle and another given particle
        """
        tot = 0
        other = other_particle.get_position()
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            tot += (self.position[i]-other[i])**2
        return math.sqrt(tot)
    def get_updated_velocity(self,other_particle):
        """
        updates the future velocity of the particle due to the acceleration
        by another particle
        """
        distance_vector = []
        other = other_particle.get_position()
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            distance_vector.append(self.position[i]-other[i])
        distance_squared = 0
        for item in distance_vector:
            distance_squared += item**2
        distance = math.sqrt(distance_squared)
        force = -self.G*self.mass*other_particle.get_mass()/(distance_squared)
        for i in range(len(self.velocity)):
            self.updated_velocity[i] = self.updated_velocity[i]+self.time_interval*force*(distance_vector[i])/(self.mass*(distance))
    def update_velocity(self):
        """
        updates the velocity of the particle
        """
        self.velocity = self.updated_velocity.copy()
def update_particles(particle_list):
    """
    updates the position of all the particles
    """
    for i in range(len(particle_list)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(particle_list)):
            particle_list[i].get_updated_velocity(particle_list[j])
            particle_list[j].get_updated_velocity(particle_list[i])
    for i in range(len(particle_list)):
        particle_list[i].update_velocity()
        particle_list[i].get_updated_position()
    for i in range(len(particle_list)):
        particle_list[i].update_position()      
#the list of particles
partList = [Particle(1,[0,0],[0,0]),Particle(1,[1,0],[0,0])]
#how many iterations I perform
for i in range(100000):
    update_particles(partList)
#prints out the final position of all the particles
for item in partList:
    print(item)
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Further Edit:

I decided to implement the Leapfrog method and I have developed some code that once again runs and seems to work well (at least in the command line). However when I added plotting functionality and analysed it there seemed to be another problem. Again the system seemed to go too far and the energy again increased without bound. I have attached a picture of the output I get to showcase the problem. If I again had just two particles of equal mass they again pass each other and continue away from each other without stopping. Thus there must be a bug in my code I am not finding.

If anyone can help it will be much appreciated.

My Code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Particle:
    """
    Represents a single particle
    """
    def __init__(self,mass,position,velocity):
        """
        Initialize the particle
        """
        self.G = 6.67408*10**-11
        self.time_step = 10**2
        self.mass = mass
        self.dimensions = len(position)
        self.position = position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.acceleration = [0 for i in range(len(position))]
        self.next_position = position
        self.next_velocity = velocity
        self.next_acceleration = [0 for i in range(len(position))]
    def __str__(self):
        """
        A string representation of the particle
        """
        return "A Particle with mass: " + str(self.mass) + " and position: " + str(self.position) + " and velocity:" + str(self.velocity) 
    def get_mass(self):
        return self.mass
    def get_position(self):
        return self.position
    def get_velocity(self):
        return self.velocity
    def get_acceleration(self):
        return self.acceleration
    def get_next_position(self):
        return self.next_position
    def put_next_position(self):
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            self.next_position[i] = self.position[i] + self.time_step*self.velocity[i]+0.5*self.time_step**2*self.acceleration[i]
    def put_next_velocity(self):
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            self.next_velocity[i] = self.velocity[i] + 0.5*self.time_step*(self.acceleration[i]+self.next_acceleration[i])
    def update_position(self):
        self.position = self.next_position.copy()
    def update_velocity(self):
        self.velocity = self.next_velocity.copy()  
    def update_acceleration(self):
        self.acceleration = self.next_acceleration.copy()
    def reset_acceleration(self):
        self.acceleration = [0 for i in range(self.dimensions)]
    def reset_future_acceleration(self):
        self.next_acceleration = [0 for i in range(self.dimensions)]
    def calculate_acceleration(self,other_particle):
        """
        Increments the acceleration of the particle due to the force from 
        a single other particle
        """
        distances = []
        other = other_particle.get_position()
        distance_squared = 0
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            distance_squared += (self.position[i]-other[i])**2
            distances.append(self.position[i]-other[i])
        distance = math.sqrt(distance_squared)
        force = -self.G*self.mass*other_particle.get_mass()/distance_squared
        acc = []
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            acc.append(force*distances[i]/(distance*self.mass))
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            self.acceleration[i] += acc[i]
    def calculate_future_acceleration(self,other_particle):
        """
        Increments the future acceleration of the particle due to the force from 
        a single other particle
        """
        distances = []
        other = other_particle.get_next_position()
        distance_squared = 0
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            distance_squared += (self.next_position[i]-other[i])**2
            distances.append(self.next_position[i]-other[i])
        distance = math.sqrt(distance_squared)
        force = -self.G*self.mass*other_particle.get_mass()/distance_squared
        acc = []
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            acc.append(force*distances[i]/(distance*self.mass))
        for i in range(self.dimensions):
            self.next_acceleration[i] += acc[i]

def update_all(particleList):
    for i in range(len(particleList)):
        particleList[i].reset_acceleration()
        for j in range(len(particleList)):
            if i != j:
                particleList[i].calculate_acceleration(particleList[j])
    for i in range(len(particleList)):
        particleList[i].put_next_position()
    for i in range(len(particleList)):
        particleList[i].reset_future_acceleration()
        for j in range(len(particleList)):
            if i != j:
                particleList[i].calculate_future_acceleration(particleList[j])
    for i in range(len(particleList)):
        particleList[i].put_next_velocity()
    for i in range(len(particleList)):
        particleList[i].update_position()
        particleList[i].update_velocity()
partList = [Particle(1,[0,0],[0,0]),Particle(1,[1,0],[0,0])]

Alist = [[],[]]
Blist = [[],[]]
for i in range(10000):
    Alist[0].append(partList[0].get_position()[0])
    Alist[1].append(partList[0].get_position()[1])
    Blist[0].append(partList[1].get_position()[0])
    Blist[1].append(partList[1].get_position()[1])
    update_all(partList)

plt.scatter(Alist[0],Alist[1],color="r")
plt.scatter(Blist[0],Blist[1],color="b")
plt.grid() 
plt.show()
for item in partList:
    print(item)
```

[image: A zoomed in plot]

Could someone please tell me where is the error I am making in my code.

Comment: Precision problem or accumulation approx error when adding squares to total. Maybe numpy can help improving the precision

Comment: Non-conservation of energy due to error accumulation is a major defect of Euler integration. If you use a small enough time step it's ok for simulating small systems where everything has near-circular orbits. Otherwise, you need to use a [symplectic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator), which _will_ conserve energy (to be more precise, it conserves a Hamiltonian that is closely related to the true energy of the system).

Comment: One popular symplectic integrator is [verlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) integration, but my personal favourite is [synchronised leap-frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Does not help. I tried replacing the float with the in-built python Decimal class set to 1000 decimal places. I got the same problem...

Comment: You're updating each particle pair twice. Change your condition from i != j to i < j (or start the j loop from i+1)

Comment: @samgak Thank you, Now the error is a lot less but it the particles still pass by each other and keep moving away from each other indefinitely.

Comment: Using Decimal can reduce approximation error, but 1000 places is probably overkill. However, you're calling `math.sqrt`, which just returns a `float`. Instead, you need to use the `Decimal.sqrt` method. Also, when calculating the force you can reduce the error a little by directly using the squared distance, rather than taking the square root of the squared distance and squaring it again.

Comment: FWIW, doing orbit sims purely in the CLI is a bit abstract. It's a lot easier if you can also plot the orbits so you can see if the orbits look plausible or crazy. :)

Comment: Just to give you an idea of how bad Euler integration is: doing a 2-body sim of the orbit of Mars (i.e. just the Sun & Mars), the orbit won't even close up unless the time step size is roughly 1 day or less.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you. I am now using 100 decimal places and have replaced math.sqrt with decimal.Decimal.sqrt and have also done the other optimization you gave. However I am still getting very similar answers to when I used math and float. I guess the problem is with the Euler method and I should switch to something like Runge-Kutta 4.

Comment: @PM2Ring I was planning on adding plotting functionality but I wanted to see that my code actually worked before I did this. That would have been the next thing I did after the code started working.

Comment: Runge-Kutta 4 _is_ more accurate than Euler, but it still suffers from energy conservation problems. Try leap-frog! It's very easy & gives excellent results.

Comment: @PM2Ring I will try leapfrog and post the results over here.

Comment: @PM2Ring I have implemented leapfrog (in a completely new implementation) and it works like a charm!

Comment: Excellent! Maybe you should post your new code as an answer, or maybe wait until you have done a plotting version. There's not much Leapfrog code on SO, and a Python example would be good.

Comment: @PM2Ring I have posted my synchronized Leapfrog code but there seems to be an error again. I have added plotting functionality and have added a picture which hopefully will help. Could you please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Implement [Velocity Verlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet) instead. It gives you the velocity of the particles at the same instant as the coordinates and you can thus compute the total energy of the system. If everything is fine, it should remain pretty constant. If it drifts or goes wild as the particles approach each other, either your equations are wrong or the timestep is simply far too large. Note that neither Euler nor RK4 are symplectic integrators and are thus not suitable for integrating the equations of motion of Hamiltonian systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in the code is that it uses the Euler method which is quite inaccurate as the number of iterations increase (just O(h) compared to other methods which can be O(h^4) or even better). To fix this would require a fundamental restructure of the code and so I would say that this code is not really accurate for an N-body simulation (it plays up for 2 particles, as I add more and more the error can only increase).

Thanks to @samgak and @PM2Ring for helping me remove a bug and optimize my code but overall this code is unusable...

EDIT: I have implemented the leapfrog method mentioned in the comments from scratch and have found it to work perfectly. It is very simple to understand and implement and it works too!

Further EDIT: I thought I had the leapfrog method working. Turns out that there was another bug in it I only saw when I added GUI functionality.